# Sonar runner works fine for .NET projects in command-line, but reports missing PDBs in Jenkins

Tags: .net, jenkins, sonarqube, opencover

I'm using Sonar with OpenCover to collect code coverage info of my C# projects using Jenkins as the CI system. Sobar server is v4.3 and the runner is versioned 2.3 on the test machine.

The tricky part is: when I run sonar runner from the command line of the test machine (Server 2008R2), it works perfect with OpenCover and collects the coverage data after the tests are finished. For example:

```
    14:31:36.479 INFO  - Committing...
    14:31:36.708 INFO  - Visited Classes 53 of 114 (46.49)
    14:31:36.710 INFO  - Visited Methods 193 of 427 (45.2)
    14:31:36.710 INFO  - Visited Points 1804 of 4024 (44.83)
    14:31:36.711 INFO  - Visited Branches 862 of 2012 (42.84)
    14:31:36.712 INFO  -
```

BUT if I set it to run the exact same commands from a Jenkins job, it still executes tests properly, but fails to collect the coverage info and complaining on missing PDBs or wrong profiler configuration:

```
    15:33:00.595 INFO  - Committing...
    15:33:00.879 INFO  - No results, this could be for a number of reasons. The most common reasons are:
    15:33:00.879 INFO  -     1) missing PDBs for the assemblies that match the filter         please review the
    15:33:00.879 INFO  -     output file and refer to the Usage guide (Usage.rtf) about filters.
    15:33:00.879 INFO  -     2) the profiler may not be registered correctly, please refer to the Usage
    15:33:00.879 INFO  -     guide and the -register switch.
```

Then the code coverage reports on the Sonar dashboard is 0%.

Some of you folks may already experienced this --- could it be related to a configuration issue somewhere? I checked SonarQube's site and there is no such info; surf over the web, and still very few talked about this and thought it might be a bug in Sonar.

My initial thought was that when I run the commands for example "SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre7 & C:\sonar_runner\sonar-runner-2.3\bin\sonar-runner.bat", and it's under my account; and running the same commands via Jenkins and it's under local system account because it's executed by the Jenkins Windows service. But checking the environment settings from Sonar-runner's outputs and seems both are pretty close.

Any clue on the cause of missing reporting on the coverage data? Great thanks :-)

Comment: The problem is partially solved that by modifying the sonar-project.properties file: use "sonar.gallio.runner=Local" instead of 
"sonar.gallio.runner=IsolatedProcess", so the committing will pick up the right info. BUT it comes with another problem --- no test isexecuted, so the coverage is still 0%. More clues on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It could be an issue with the registration if the profiler DLLs.

You can manually register them using regsvr32 and then drop -register switch. Build servers sometimes run as services and this has been the resolution.

Alternatively it could be the assemblies under test are being copied to another location (isolation?) but the PDBs aren't the -targetdir option can be used to correct that.

More information about OpenCover can be found on the wiki https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/wiki/Usage or in the supplied docs when it us installed (nuget/msi/zip)

Comment: Thank you Shaun :-) Could you help and elaborate more on how to configure OpenCover from Sonar? Seems it's all embedded into the byte code.

Besides, I run "Gallio.Utility.exe VerifyInstallation" and get this info:
Gallio Utility - Version 3.4 build 12
...
Plugin 'Gallio.VisualStudio.Tip90' is disabled: The plugin depends on another disabled plugin: 'Gallio.VisualStudio.Shell90'.'

Could this also be related?

Comment: Sorry I haven't a clue, I use OpenCover a lot (but never used Sonar) - the guys have a good forum and readily respond to people asking questions (they may not monitor StackOverflow)